# PHPStorm: Goto Laravel Method Declaration

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Usually in PHPStorm to go to method declaration in Windows you can [ctrl+click] on the method name and PHPStorm will open the file that the method is in. However, that's not working with the Laravel facade pattern.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Inever tried but maybe using this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532?pr=phpStorm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this package:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

All the info is in the github repo.